# Easy way to center ANYTHING inside of a <div> to the very middle of the page

Tags: html, css

I have this code:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
    function newWord() {
      var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
      request.onload = function() {
          // get the file contents
          var fileContent = this.responseText;
          // split into lines
          var fileContentLines = fileContent.split( '\n' );
          // get a random index (line number)
          var randomLineIndex = Math.floor( Math.random() * fileContentLines.length );
          // extract the value
          var randomLine = fileContentLines[ randomLineIndex ];

          // add the random line in a div
          document.getElementsByName( 'random-phrase' )[0].innerHTML = randomLine;
      };
      request.open( 'GET', 'dictionary.txt', true );
      request.send();
    }
    function define() {
      var word = document.getElementsByName ( 'random-phrase' )[0].innerHTML;
      window.open("http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/" + word)
    }
    </script>
    <title>word-a-day web</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1 style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 50px;" name="random-phrase">Loading a word...</h1>
    <button onclick="newWord()">New Word</button>
    <button onclick="define()">Define</button>
    <script>newWord()</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I want to center everything in the  to the very middle of the page. I'd love to see how to center all of the buttons and text and everything.
**Thanks in advance!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all wrap them in a div for eg. called `#toCenter` and apply the following css:

```
#toCenter{
  position: fixed; /*or absolute*/
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  -moz-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  -o-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```

This method only works IE9 and further.

Comment: Thanks, this really helped! This is by far the simplest way to center anything! **+1**

Answer (score 0):

To support IE8 as well you could use `display:table;`.

The HTML would be:

```
<body>    
<div id="tablecont">
    <div id="rowcont">
        <div id="cellcont">
            <div class="container">
                words<br/>
                other words<br/>
                heaps of words
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

And the CSS:

```
body,html {
    height:100%;
}
#tablecont {
    display:table;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}
#rowcont {
    display:table-row;
}
#cellcont {
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
.container {
    max-width:50%;
    margin:0 auto;
    text-align:center;
}
```

A jsfiddle of this is located here: http://jsfiddle.net/ryanpither/nme67079/

Note the `height:100%;` declaration on the `body,html`. This is so the table can expand to the full height of the page.

This solution will also keep the content in the document 'flow', compared to a `position:fixed;` or `position:absolute;` solution.

Support for display:table; :  http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-table

Support for 2Dtransforms : http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d

Comment: That's too much ugly solution. Though it is sometime useful.

Comment: Sure it is ugly but if you need to support IE8 then it is necessary.

Comment: No. There's another ways too.

Comment: Besides using actual tables, and not using javascript, what other ways can you vertically and horizontally align a container element of unknown height and unknown width?

Comment: Yeah we can and yes OP has no requirement for unknown width and height. The OP can set a fixed width then center them.

Comment: That is an assumption that you've made. This answer works without assumptions.